# Convertion from Hex to Dual leads always to std::out_of_range at memory location

Tags: c++, hex

I'm writing a c++ program that converts a list of characters to a double number. So basically i convert the characters to a hex number and then convert the hex to double using this method

```
#include <cstdio>

double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr)
{
     union
     {
         long long  i;
         double    d;
     } value;

     value.i = std::stoll(hexstr, nullptr, 16);

     return value.d;
}
```

hexstr is the hex number that i want to convert to double. I'm able to have good  conversion results but only if the double number is positive if it's negative I always have this error " Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location "

For example "3fc87916804e22df" gives "0.19119530930426884" But "bf9f9dca2676f181" gives "-9.2559631349317831e+61" which is a wrong result and leads to the error

Comment: Do note that accessing the non active member of a union is undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What is the string you are attempting to convert? Does it fit in a `long long`?  `std::stoll` throws `std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type.

Comment: I mean a test case that causes the error.

Comment: Sure, for example 
"3fc87916804e22df" gives "0.19119530930426884"
But  "bf9f9dca2676f181" gives "-9.2559631349317831e+61" which is a wrong result and leads to that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) it says:

> ## Exceptions
>
> ...
>    - `std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (`std::strtol` or `std::strtoll`) sets `errno` to `ERANGE`.